# First order logic

Tags: lo.logic

How to prove that in a first-order logic, the models of a theory cannot be only the interpretations with finite domains?

Comment: While a nice question, it’s not really research-level, so this sort of question would be more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7):

If the theory $T$ proves (for some natural number $n \in {\mathbb Z}_+$) the sentence

$$(\forall y_0) \cdots (\forall y_n) \bigvee_{0 \leq i < j \leq n} y_i = y_j$$

then every mcodel of $T$ will be an interpretation with a finite domain.  Otherwise, the compactness theorem in the language ${\mathcal L}(\{ c_i : i \in {\mathbb N} \})$ where ${\mathcal L}$ is the language of $T$ and the $c_i$'s are new constant symbols applied to the set of sentences

$$T \cup \{ c_i \neq c_j :  0 \leq i < j \in {\mathbb N} \}$$
shows that there must be infinite models of $T$.

Comment: The collection of disjunctions on the first two lines is often proved in the equivalent form "if it has any finite models, it has models of unboundedly large finite size".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct: I think you mean "if it has a model of arbitrary large size then it has models of unboundedly large size!?" – Anna Fred 0 secs ago

Comment: Any way, how this could help in the proof?